# A Riddle You Know Very Well

Tags: riddle, word

> Big, I'm not quiet.
>
> Full, I'm not free.
>
> Clean, I'm not red.
>
> Blood, someone's dead.

**What am I?**

Hint #1

> The title.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You also might be..

> **Hands**

Big, I'm not quiet.

> "To give a big hand" means to applaud, which is pretty loud

Full, I'm not free.

> "To have your hands full" means that you're occupied, not free

Clean, I'm not red.

> "To keep your hands clean" means to be guiltless, i.e. not "red-handed"

Blood, someone's dead.

> "To have blood on your hands" means you're guilty of killing someone

Title

> You use them every day, so you must know them pretty well by now and as @hagfy suggested in the comments, you "Know something like the back of your hand"

Comment: This answer looks good, nice work.  Just wanted to add, the title could refer to when you rot13(xabj fbzrguvat "yvxr gur onpx bs lbhe unaq").

Comment: you figured it out. I’ve gotta hand it to you.

Comment: Regarding Hint #1: When hover on the title, you can see the Hand cursor

Comment: I don’t have a cursor. I’m using a touch screen... you get the idea.

Comment: @hagfy You got it. Interestingly, there is an idiom for the other side as well rot13(xabj yvxr gur cnyz bs unaq), so knowing both sides one must know it doubly well.

Comment: @kedarguru Ah yes, that rings a bell.  I'll index that for later reference.  Thumbs up to you for this puzzle!  ...phalanges?

Answer (score 8):

You might be..

> **A bullet**

Big, I'm not quiet.

> Large bullets usually come with a very loud bang when shot/on impact

Full, I'm not free.

> A live round is full with gunpowder and the bullet itself is encased in a shell, not able to escape unless fired

Clean, I'm not red.

> Blood is red, and usually shows up when shooting someone

Blood, someone's dead.

> Bullets with high velocity tend to kill people

Title

> Riddle might refer to "riddled with bullets". This got very gruesome all of a sudden.

Answer (score 8):

Are you:

> A heart?

Big, I'm not quiet.

> Someone who is "big hearted" is emotional, and so is not quiet about their feelings.

Full, I'm not free.

> Someone with a "full heart" is weighed down with worries, so in a figurative sense they are not free.

Clean, I'm not red.

> When a literal heart is drained of blood, like most organs it ceases to be red in colour. Alternatively I was thinking figuratively that a "clean heart" can mean free from guilt, so perhaps you mean that a person is free from embarrassment or shame (which can make a person red)?

Blood, someone's dead.

> If you can see blood coming from someone's heart, they are most likely dead.

And the clue: *A Riddle You Know Very Well*

> You know your own heart.

Answer (score 3):

This seems too obvious but I give it a try:

> Meat grinder

Clean, I'm not red.

> If you clean it there should be nothing red(meat) be left.

Blood, someone's dead.

> Sure if you make meat with it there is someone dead and blood..

Big, I'm not quiet.

> The industrial machines are mostly not quiet.

Full, I'm not free.

> If it is filled it is for sure not free. Could also hint to "Meat-free".

Comment: This is a good answer! Unfortunately it is not what I am looking for.